# Why did Troy's arm still hurt after two months?

Tags: plot-explanation, community

In Community episode S03E19 Curriculum Unavailable, when the study group is talking about what a crazy year they have had, they show an incident in which Troy slams his hand against the table.(This incident could not have happened after they were expelled, for obvious reasons)

This happened 2 months after they were expelled(according to Shirley's words at the start of the episode)

After they finish telling the Doctor about these incidents we see that Britta squeezes Troy's hand and he cries out in pain.

Now, I guess there has been a mistake because I think even a broken hand will be repaired in two months 
So is there a problem with the Community Timeline?

Comment: Two months to heal depends on the type of injury.  Even if it's "healed" doesn't mean that it can't still be stiff and sore and hard to use until physical therapy has been completed.

Comment: @DForck42 i expect this is the rite answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

As DForck42 correctly noted in his comment, depending on the gravity of the injury it is not unreasonable to still hurt after two months.

Even if healed, some injuries will continue to hurt for years or even a whole lifetime.

Obviously Troy's injury was not that bad, but my guess is that they did not care too much about the minor detail of the time frame and mostly cared more about using the reference to the injury for the comedic effect.